# WYSIWYG Editor Suggestion

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, wysiwyg

Wondering if anyone can suggest a WYSIWYG editor for a rails project.

Some requirements:

- Prefer no iframes
- Need the ability to add a Select List to the toolbar, to allow the user to add code snippets at the current location
- Play nice with simple_form
- Nice to have voice to text conversion.

http://mindmup.github.io/bootstrap-wysiwyg/ : Looks fantastic, accept it needs a DIV so will not play nicely with simnple_form

http://hackerwins.github.io/summernote/features.html : Cant see a way to insert the custom toolbar and functionality

Comment: This question should be asked at softwarerecs stack exchange if there is not an answer that fits your needs http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=WYSIWYG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been using bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails in combination with simple form. It pops up the toolbar on top of the input field without additional modifications. What problems do you see?

Comment: Thanks Danny! I cannot see any way to add my own custom toolbar buttons to the toolbar, and/or insert custom tags/text at the cursor position.

Comment: You can add custom toolbar buttons, as described in https://github.com/jhollingworth/bootstrap-wysihtml5#custom-templates-for-toolbar-buttons

Comment: If you have trouble doing so, I can help you with that, as I've applied it in one of my projects